# Mongoose to Return only match Object/Item

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to retrieve only matched object from the mongoose query. I tried different approaches but still I'm unable to do so.

Response right now:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "61ac08008c3d6ad03a20c8f7",
        "pages": [
            {
                "_id": "61ac1dcf45b78934dca130c4",
                "page_number": "2",
                "page_content": "Rasdsa"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected Response:

```
        "pages": [
            {
                "_id": "61ac1dcf45b78934dca130c4",
                "page_number": "2",
                "page_content": "Rasdsa"
            }
        ]
```

It will be more better if we get only unwind object from query.

Current query

```
await BooksModel.find( { book_id:"2"},{ pages: { $elemMatch: { page_number: "2" } }}, {"$project": {"pages":"1"}}).exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the `_id` by providing a 0 as the value in the project stage.

Like:

```
await BooksModel.find( { book_id:"2"},{ pages: { $elemMatch: { page_number: "2" } }}, {"$project": {"pages":"1", "_id": "0"}}).exec();
```